# Ignoring folders in TortoiseSVN...?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using SVN you can right click a folder "TEST" and add it to the ignore list.  Does that make SVN inore all folders named "TEST" in the project?

I have a project with many different directories and within almost all these seperate directories is a folder named "TEST", is there a way to set the svn:ignore to make SVN ignore every folder named "TEST" in the whole project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not—ignoring a folder only ignores it in that folder (and not recursively).

To do it recursively (i.e., for all folders in the project), right click the top-level folder and choose Properties, then click New..., and choose svn:ignore.  Put

```
TEST
```

into the text box, and check "Apply property recursively."  This will apply it to every folder **currently** in the project, but you will still have to manually add it to any **new** folders.

**Warning:** This will overwrite (i.e., remove) any other ignores you may have set in the folder structure. (thanks to Pekka for this)

Comment: Just note that this will overwrite any other ignores you may have set in the folder structure.

Comment: Good point, that slipped past me.  Added that to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, another option is to add entries to the *Global ignore pattern* in the general settings. This will only affect your PC; it's not persisted as a property in the repository.

Right-click the TortoiseSVN icon in your toolbar and choose **Settings**. In the *General* area there's a section for **Global ignore pattern**. You can add entries separated by spaces, like this: bin lib obj *.o

Comment: How to do this I've been looking for this solution for a long time. How to implement this for example to ignore the database folder *database   . Is it?